# Why are my custom/explicit measure Data Labels not reversing positions along with the reversal of stacked columns?

Tags: powerbi, dax

[Before Column Reversal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCPfN.png)
[image: Before Column Reversal]

[After Column Reversal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQdpd.png)
[image: After Column Reversal]

Data Label Measure:

```
DIVIDE(
    [Sample Count],
    CALCULATE(
        [Sample Count],
        ALLEXCEPT(
            'fSampleResultsOilWater',
            'dDates'[Q Year]
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?